# Mui V5 StaticDatePicker - programmatically change the month being displayed in the 'day' view without setting a value?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-date-picker

I'm using the StaticDatePicker from Mui v5. I have some dates available in the datepicker a few months in the future (Nov and Dec) - the user needs to manually scroll to them to select them.

I tried setting the `value` to the minDate so the calendar view renders by showing November, but this results in the user not being able to select the `minDate` (since it won't trigger an onChange event)

Is there a way to programmatically change what month the StaticDatePicker is showing (without modifying the selected value)?